# How do I SELECT FROM..WHERE then JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to SELECT all records from a table that match 'status' as 'Open', and THEN perform a left join with another table. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT (ticket.* WHERE ticket.status = 'Open'), ticketupdate.updatetime
FROM ticket
INNER JOIN ticketupdate ON ticketupdate.ticketid = ticket.ticketid
```

Comment: Move the WHERE clause to the end.

Answer (score 4):

Simple you can do *left join* with `where` clause

```
select tk.*, tu.updatetime 
from ticket tk 
left join ticketupdate tu on tu.ticketid  = tk.ticketid 
where tk.status = 'Open';
```

Comment: I think this is the correct solution, but I believe that OP wants an inner join.

Answer (score 3):

You can put in a nested SELECT

```
SELECT ticket.* , ticketupdate.updatetime
FROM (SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE status = 'Open') AS ticket
LEFT JOIN ticketupdate 
    ON ticketupdate.ticketid = ticket.ticketid
```

Comment: There is no need for the derived table (`as ticket`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mostly use mssql and if i don't put in the 'as ticket' there it gives an error

Comment: I was not referring to the actual alias, but the fact that you used a derived table at all (I used it to indicate which part of the query is useless in case you have not heard of the term "derived table). The alias itself of course is required  _if_ you use a derived table - but the derived table is useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah okay, yeah I see what you mean.yes if you just put the where at the end (like the other answer shows) it would work as well

Comment: I see this answer tries to limit the number of rows first before joining.  Would that reduce the computation / memory as it left joining with fewer number of rows ?

Comment: @EBDS Not really.
Any halfway decend database-engine gets a query and then optimises it themself, which they can do much better then the absolute majority of developers.